# can't convert String into Integer from inside hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display a given value from a block of search data per result in the listing. I am getting the error "can't convert String into Integer"  How do I display the next level array inside my linked_agents?

My code for the particular column is such

```
    <td>
      <% if result['primary_type'] === "resource" or result['primary_type'] === "digital_object" or result['primary_type'] === "accession" %>
          <%= display_agents(result) %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
```

and the code

```
  def display_agents(hash, opts = {})
    object = JSON.parse( hash["json"] )["linked_agents"]
    object2 = object["_resolved"]
    html = "<div class='audit-display-compact'><small>"
    html << "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>"
    html << "<li>#{object2}</li>"
    html << "</ul>"
    html << "</small></div><div class='clearfix'></div>"
    html.html_safe
  end
```

Here is what is inside linked_agents.

```
[{"_resolved"=>{"names"=>[{"sort_name"=>"John Smith"}]}}]
```

How can I get all the sort_name's to display the data?  There could be more than one _resolved each containing a sort_name.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your object, there doesn't appear to be a sort name in the parent object (but rather in the JSON value contained). I suspect your logic is working fine, you just need to do some work on that piece of data. Can you verify that your logic is working (by either inserting a <% debugger %> or some static text in the <td> element)?

Comment: the <td> element is working fine. I can place regular text and it works and anything from the primary object.

Comment: Alright, so this confirms that your logic is sound. The issue is that there is no "sort_name" key in the results hash. You need to somewhere handle `result['json']` in such a way that you can access the proper value inside of it. Without an understanding of your application and the information contained in the "json" data, it will prove difficult for us to parse. I would recommend showing the action providing these results and explaining the intent of `results['sort_name']`.

Comment: I shortened the search_data to just relevant data for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More data would've been more helpful than less data, but essentially your problem is this: "json" contains a string. Nothing more. Not an object. Nothing you could reference with `results[]`. Assuming the JSON is all properly formatted, what you would need to do is something like this:

```
<%= JSON.parse( result["json"] )["linked_agents"]["_resolved"]["sort_name"] %>
```

Now, this is horribly sloppy, and not the way you're going to want to accomplish your goals (assuming this is even effective with your data set). In actuality, what you'll want to do is parse that JSON into a variable, and work through in hash form.

It is difficult to clearly keep the topics at work here because there isn't a clear question. I would encourage you to make sure you have a basic familiarity of ruby arrays, hashes, and nested structures consisting thereof. Additionally, take a look at how you're retrieving the data that goes into `results["json"]`.

There are many ways to accomplish many things once your data is properly structured, but you need to have a clear understanding of these types of structure before you can work magic (and you need to possess a basic knowledge of what you *aren't* understanding before we can provide you with solutions).

I hope that is helpful. Feel free to discuss points of confusion in the comment, and I will update this answer as we approach a solution for your problem.

Comment: I decided to create some code to help display it.  I added it to the original post.  I receive an error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: I made another adjustment and got to this error. "can't convert String into Integer"

Comment: Now it is "undefined method `[]=' for #<OpenStruct>"

Comment: On what lines are you getting these errors? Why are you casting a hash to json and then the json to an OpenStruct?

Comment: I got a bit closer, but run into the "can't convert String into Integer" error.  I can't seem to get the data inside link_agents.

Comment: According to the contents you shared above, saying `[{"_resolved"=>{"names"=>[{"sort_name"=>"John Smith"}]}}]` is the contents of linked_agents, then the problem could be that it contains an array, which in turn contains _resolved. That said, you still need to share HOW you are getting this data, WHERE you are getting these errors, and WHAT you are trying to do. I cannot help you if you keep reformatting the question and providing less information.

Comment: The data comes from a search which pulls data from the database tables.  The error appears when I click to search and points at that code.  I am trying to display the sort_name in a column if the record has any.  I am modifying software that is not mine through the use of plugins.  Does this help clear anything?